# SQL Server Exception Reporting Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Seeing this is my first post of 2016, Happy New Year to all.

Once again, I'm stuck with a tricky report I must pull from SQL Server.

I have a two tables called `Documents` and `Doctype`

Columns in `Documents`:

```
File_Name, Date, Region, DoctypeID
```

Data inside this columns are as follows.

```
   00001,2016-01-06,JHB,1d187ecc
   00001,2016-01-06,JHB,bccc05f9
   00001,2016-01-06,JHB,fe697be0
   00001,2016-01-06,JHB,bbae8c73
   00002,2016-01-06,JHB,1d187ecc
   00002,2016-01-06,JHB,bccc05f9
   00002,2016-01-06,JHB,fe697be0
```

Columns in `Doctype`:

```
DoctypeID, Document_Type
```

Data inside this columns are as follows.

```
1d187ecc, Collection
bccc05f9, Image
fe697be0, Log
bbae8c73, Sent to warehouse.
```

My query needs to give me the below result, using the data above.

```
File_Name,Collection, Image, Log, Sent to Warehouse,Region
00001,         1,       1,    1,       1,            JHB
00002,         1,       1,    1,       0,            JHB
```

I hope the above makes sense, how would I go about doing this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I think you're looking for [Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: HI @JodyT Thank you for the response, I have very limited knowledge of Pivot in SQL, any examples?

Comment: You need to confirm whether these will be the only six columns or can there be many different other types of columns

Comment: HI @Nick.McDermaid, it will always only have these 4 document types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can try this:

```
SELECT FILE_NAME, ISNULL([Collection],0) AS [Collection], ISNULL([Image],0) AS [Image],  
ISNULL([Log],0) AS [Log],  ISNULL([Sent to warehouse],0) AS [Sent to warehouse], Region
FROM (  
    SELECT FILE_NAME, Document_Type, COUNT(Document_Type) AS Frequency, Region 
    FROM documents d,doctype dt WHERE d.DoctypeID = dt.DoctypeID 
    GROUP BY Document_Type, FILE_NAME,REGION
) AS s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Frequency)
    FOR [Document_Type] IN ([Collection], [Image], [Log], [Sent to warehouse])
)AS pvt
```

Here is a detail [reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query) that you can read.